# Facebook Social Auth Login: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: django, facebook-authentication, python-social-auth

I am developing a web application using Django and python-social-auth. I want users to login with Facebook.

I have this in my python settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

When my users enter the facebook page where they should provide credentials they see an error like this:

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.
To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your 
app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

In Facebook for Developers dashboard I have added "Facebook Login" product and added redirect url:

```
http://localhost:8000/complete/facebook/
```

In settings, Website Site URL is set to: `http://localhost:8000/` and App Domains is set to `localhost`.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW this is the url that my users see when the facebook page opens:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?scope=email&state=HSfkstGUR5028DMhUzfWOSgo6fpPx29E&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3DHSfkstGUR5028DMhUzfWOSgo6fpPx29E&client_id=...&return_scopes=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the 'Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs' setting in your Facebook login app.

OR

Note the `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3DHSfkstGUR5028DMhUzfWOSgo6fpPx29E` parameter of generated url.

For some inexplicable reason Facebook requires Valid OAuth redirect URIs setting to be ***exactly*** the same as the redirect url.

So use a tool like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/, decode the url and set Valid OAuth redirect URIs to the full url. I.E:

http://localhost:8000/complete/facebook/redirect_state=HSfkstGUR5028DMhUzfWOSgo6fpPA59E

Comment: Note that Facebook started requiring Strict Mode in December 2017. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the second part of this answer to work.

Comment: The redirect_state will be unique each time the user requests a login, so adding it to the list of valid URIs isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading [`social-auth-core`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core) to at least [version 1.6.0](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160---2017-12-22) should help to resolve this. Among other changes it includes this one:

> Default `REDIRECT_STATE` to `False` in `FacebookOAuth2` backend.

This was changed as a result of [issue 141](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/141), and it causes redirect URLs to be generated without the `redirect_state` argument, whose dynamic value makes whitelisting impossible.

Once you've done this, add `https://<your-domain>/complete/facebook/` to your OAuth redirect whitelist in the Facebook developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't like `localhost` in the `Redirect URI` field in the app setup or in the `redirect_uri` parameter. To workaround it just set something in the field (I use `http://myapp.com:8000`, then add the entry `127.0.0.1 myapp.com` in your `/etc/hosts` and access the app through the new URL (http://myapp.com:8000).

Comment: Actually it works just fine. Maybe they changed something recently.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 4th April 2018, day i face the same issue, the only solution i found is:
**Valid OAuth redirect URIs** must be set to be exactly the same as the redirect url

More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/